# unable to run the bundled example of QPID Proton-j

Tags: java, amqp, qpid

I am new to QPID and AMQP in general. 
I have setup a QPID broker 6.1.0 with a virtual host with name "example".
This virtual host has a queue named "test-queue-1" which is bound with "amq.direct" exchange.

Now, I am trying to use the java messenger examples given with QPID proton to send and receive to and from the queue.
Can someone tell me the format of the command line command to run the send and receive classes.
I am trying the following commands but none of them are working:

```
sh send -a amqp://localhost:5672/example/test-queue-1 firstMessage message1 message2 message3
```

and

```
sh recv -a amqp://localhost:5672/example/test-queue-1
```

Comment: When asking questions it is good form to include what you mean by not working, i.e. an error log or stack trace etc.

Comment: @TimBish: there were no errors and what was not working is that the receiver did not get any messages. i figured out that the messages addressed to a binding key work as expected.